# WCF parse data from stream

Tags: c#, web-services, web, form-data

I have a service like following:

and when i post data from Postman with form-data in body like this:

"

```
------WebKitFormBoundarycTodfAxkLS0DHW9R
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

host
------WebKitFormBoundarycTodfAxkLS0DHW9R
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

P@ssword
------WebKitFormBoundarycTodfAxkLS0DHW9R--
```

".
I have a question. How to parse data to get username and password in my webservice(WCF) ?

Somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: want to do it at code end or in postman api? @Dan

Comment: I want to to it in my code, guy

Comment: and what you have tried so far as it is not clear from your question that how will you acheive this?

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15 : thank you :)